# Count of values grouped by a row id

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

My data looks like the below,

[image]

I want to sum up the count of occurrences of *ALL*. This should be grouped by Id. So the output should look like,

```
ID Count
1    5
2    4
```

My query looks like,

```
select id,
       (count(Monday) + count(Tuesday) + count(Wednesday) + count(Thursday) +
       count(Friday) + count(Saturday) + count(Sunday)) as 'Count'
  from Report
 where Monday = 'ALL'
    or Tuesday = 'ALL'
    or Wednesday = 'ALL'
    or Thursday = 'ALL'
    or Friday = 'ALL'
    or Saturday = 'ALL'
    or Sunday = 'ALL'
 group by Id;
```

This query is giving me the result as,

```
ID Count
 1    5
 2    6
```

which is incorrect for Id 2. The value for Friday for the second row is an empty string.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4eb03ac913b4b953226e33dd55292c5)

Comment: Do you have multiple rows with the same ID? `GROUP BY` is for combining multiple rows with the same value in a column.

Comment: `count(case when Monday = 'ALL' then 1 end)`

Comment: its because of your `or` condition.

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: `COUNT(Friday)` will count any non-null values. An empty string is not `NULL`, so it gets counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use counting for all days of a week with case being equal to `ALL`

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(Monday='ALL') + COUNT(Tuesday='ALL') + COUNT(Wednesday='ALL')+ 
           COUNT(Thursday='ALL') + COUNT(Friday='ALL') + COUNT(Saturday='ALL')+ 
           COUNT(Sunday='ALL')
  FROM `Report` 
 GROUP BY Id ;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ccadcb4c363c2da52fd248b0e51fa78)</kbd>

Comment: that does not work. its returning null. You can try it on that dbfiddle link.

Comment: well, SUM aggregation is needed to be replaced with COUNT @Bisoux

Comment: @Bisoux, your fiddle input is also not right, and always explain what you want in your question.

Comment: @Fahmi whats not right with the fiddle input. And what i want is cleary explained in the question.